# Java, Transfer money service and concurrency issue

Tags: java, concurrency, transactions, synchronized

I have code like this:

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = RuntimeException.class)
    synchronized public void transfer(@NonNull final TransferModel transferModel) {
        log.info("Start processing money transfer from user: {} to receiver: {}. Transfer amount: {}", transferModel.getOwnerId(), transferModel
                .getReceiverId(), transferModel.getAmount());

        final AccountEntity ownerAccount = findByOwner(transferModel.getOwnerId());
        final AccountEntity receiverAccount = findByOwner(transferModel.getReceiverId());

        log.info("Owner balancer before transfer: {}. Receiver balance before transfer {}", ownerAccount.getBalance(), receiverAccount.getBalance());

        if (ownerAccount.getBalance().compareTo(transferModel.getAmount()) < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Owner has insufficient amount of money");
        }

        withdrawFromOwnerAccount(ownerAccount, transferModel.getAmount());
        depositToReceiverAccount(receiverAccount, transferModel.getAmount());

        log.info("Transfer money finished successful");
        log.info("Owner balancer after transfer: {}. Receiver balance after transfer {}", ownerAccount.getBalance(), receiverAccount.getBalance());
    }
```

Simple method which take moeny from owner and pass to the receiver. This soulution is naive because it can't handle more than one transfer at a time. How can I ensure that this method will handle more then one request and be safe in concurrent env ?

Comment: Methods can't handle more than one request. Methods are called. And in your case, as the method is synchronized this happens in sequence. As we know exactly **zero** about your environment - how are supposed to understand what exactly will happen when you execute this method in parallel? Sorry, but this question is way to broad.

Answer (score 2):

As ghostCat mentioned, we're not familiar with your env so if any of the methods that "looks naive" have side-effect, we won't know it.

That said, assuming that this is a very simple and straightforward code and the methods-names reflects what they're doing, I'd argue that we don't have to sync *all* the method, but rather only the critical part:

```
withdrawFromOwnerAccount(ownerAccount, transferModel.getAmount());
depositToReceiverAccount(receiverAccount, transferModel.getAmount());
```

We can sync this part using the account:

```
synchronized (ownerAccount) {
    withdrawFromOwnerAccount(ownerAccount, transferModel.getAmount());
}
synchronized (receiverAccount) {
    depositToReceiverAccount(receiverAccount, transferModel.getAmount());
}
```

By doing so we are able to execute this method in parallel, and lock threads only when the giver/receiver is already in the middle of executing another transaction.

Note: in order to apply this approach you'll have to make sure that you don't have two objects for the same account!